# Why I'm not able to delete all taxonomy terms tree?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I'm using custom drush command for flushing my custom vocabulary:

```
    function drush_mm_category_delete_all() {
  $vocab = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary::load('mm_vocab');

  if (! $vocab) {
    throw new Exception("Missing 'mm_vocab' vocabulary");
  }

  $tree = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
    ->getStorage("taxonomy_term")
    ->loadTree('mm_vocab', 0, NULL, FALSE);

  drush_print('Amount of terms to delete: ' . count($tree));
  $counter = 0;


  foreach($tree as $term) {
    $term_entity = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($term->tid);
    $term_entity->delete();
    $counter++;
  }

  drush_print('Amount of deleted terms: ' . $counter);

}
```

I'm getting error:

> Error: Call to a member function delete() on null

but WTF? I see that loadTree returns flat array of all vocab term. It seems that all items are object with tid property.

If I add:

```
if ($term_entity) {
  //delete here
}
```

I'm able to run command without error, but only small amount of terms are deleted. Why?

Comment: Ok it's probably because upon parent deletion, children are also deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is correct, children are deleted automatically.

So what you can do is set the max_depth argument to 0, then you should only get the top-level terms and you can delete those.